# Is there a site for which one can search for different full gamerscores for XBOX 360 games?

Tags: xbox-360

Is there a site for which one can search for different full gamerscores for XBOX 360 games?

For example if I want a game with a full gamerscore (so far) of 50 or 1700 and seach for which games that has that?

Comment: What do you mean by 'full gamerscores'? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: There will never be a game with a gamerscore of only 50. All XBLA games are required to have a total of 200 points and full retail games 1000 points, plus however much for their DLC. That said, I'm hesitant on whether this question can remain open or not, seeing as it is a "list of X" question, which we don't really support on this site as per the [FAQ].

Comment: But there are several Kinect related with gamerscore 50 for example Kinect Fun Labs: Avatar Kinect and 6 more.

Comment: Why, to look for different full scores and the "funny" ones like Mass Effect 2 with 1355 full, Battlefield: Bad Company 2 1430 and Magic: The Gathering with full 350.

Comment: Why... why would you pick which games to play based on how much Gamerscore they offer...

Comment: Who said you should pick, just looking at different games with different gamerscore is this Forbidden? Ever heard of information, databases, datamining, sorting and that stuff?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of one that specifically allows you to sort by total score, but there are 2 that list out most (if not all) Xbox 360 games and allow you to see their scores fairly easily:

[TrueAchievements](http://www.trueachievements.com/games.aspx) lists out all games, and you can filter the Score column. The score is filtered though by their TrueAchievement score, but the real achievement total is shown in parentheses. If you filter the Score column twice into ascending order, you'll see a few of the 50 achievement ones you mention and can page through the rest. They are generally sorted in order of their total score. On Page 2 for example, you can see Star Trek D.A.C. which has a total of 235 points.

[Xbox360Achievements](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/achievements/) breaks out games by Arcade, Retail, Windows Phone, etc. They don't let you sort by score either unfortunately, but for example if you look at the list of K Arcade games and see the 50 score Kinect ones you mentioned. Under D Arcade games, you can find DeathSpank: Thongs of Virtue, which has a total of 215 points.